# BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway | Password is required for key ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm trying to setup a python script in anaconda's jupyter lab so I can connect to a remote server to retrieve some data from a maria db database.

I can connect fine from dbeaver and google colab using the following script

```
!pip install pymysql
import pymysql
!pip install paramiko
import paramiko
from paramiko import SSHClient
import pandas as pd
!pip install sshtunnel
import sshtunnel
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import ssl

#setup connection constants
ssh_host = 'serves-ip-or-domain name'
ssh_username = 'ssh-hostname'
#ssh_password = 'no needed'
database_username = 'mysql-username'
database_password = 'mysql-userpassword'
database_name = 'databasename'
localhost = '127.0.0.1'
  

mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('path/to/rsa_id', 'password-to-ssh-key-configured-with-ssh-keygen')

########################################################################################
# functions to stablish an ssh tunnel, connect to mysql and break connection and tunel #
########################################################################################

#establish an ssl tunnel to server
def open_ssh_tunnel(verbose=False):
    """Open an SSH tunnel and connect using a username and password.
    
    :param verbose: Set to True to show logging
    :return tunnel: Global SSH tunnel connection
    """
    
    if verbose:
        sshtunnel.DEFAULT_LOGLEVEL = logging.DEBUG
    
    global tunnel
    tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (ssh_host, 22),
        ssh_username = ssh_username,
        ssh_pkey = mypkey,
        remote_bind_address = ('127.0.0.1', 3306)
    )
    
    tunnel.start()
```

but when I try to open the tunnel with:

```
open_ssh_tunnel()
```

I get this error:

```
2023-06-20 11:05:04,844| ERROR   | Password is required for key ~/.ssh/id_rsa
2023-06-20 11:05:06,007| ERROR   | Could not open connection to gateway
```

the line

```
mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(id_rsa_path, key_file_password)
```

does not through an error, so I'm assuming that mypkey is fine, meaning the path given to the file and the password provided to my pkey is fine
so I'm not sure why I'm getting that error.